# Vaadin grid cannot edit previously saved item

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am using a Vaadin Grid with buffered editing. I am adding an item to it as such:

```
items.add(hashMap);
dataProvider.refreshAll();
```

Then I attempt to edit the entry. I have these two editing buttons:

```
Button cancelButton = new Button(VaadinIcon.CLOSE.create(),
                e -> editor.cancel());
Button saveButton = new Button(VaadinIcon.THUMBS_UP.create(),
                e -> editor.save());
```

I also have saveListener which does the following:

```
dataProvider.refreshAll();
```

Without it, the grid does not update.

Anyhow. Here is the issue. If I edit, and I do not write any new data, the cancel and save button works the same. And I can re-edit. All is good.

However, when I edit and write any new data. I can save, but I cannot re-edit the entry I just saved.

If I add a new entry, I can now re-edit the entry that was locked before.

It is as if that entry is not part of the grid or the dataprovider because my addSelectionListener also does not react when I select that entry. Yet, I do find it in my item-list.

Furthermore, if I add a system.out to the editing component listener, nothing is shown in the log.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You serm to use `Hashmap` as data object instead of a POJO. That will require you to add unique "id" property to your map and override `DataProvider` to use it as an identity. See full code example here: https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-with-map

Comment: That's probably it. Thank you so much!